# how to put the execution code in the section other than the .text section into the middle of the .text

Tags: c, linux, assembly, linker

i have the following test code

```
int main()
{
  int a = 10;
  __asm__ __volatile__ 
  (
     ".section test\n\t"
     "movl 20,%eax"\n\t"
  );
  int b = 20;
}
```

can anyone told me is there any method to let the code in the section test to embedded between the assignment of a and b?
using the subsection ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write some [GNU linker script](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html#SEC4) for your needs.

Comment: i remember using the script we can only define the section in the unit  of file which means if we define a new section named .combined which includes .text and test, but the test section is behind the .text or before the .text, cannot put the test section between the a = 10 and b = 20!!!